# Add Y axis to highchart dynamically at bottom of the 1st chart without reducing the size of the previous chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular8

I am trying to add new Y axis and series to already initialized chart at the bottom of the initialized chart.
Right now when I add the Y axis, it is getting added in the same level. I tried adding "top" (which offset from the top of the chart), but the new chart is getting cropped as the area of the already initialized chart got fixed (400px).
I tried increasing the height of the container before adding the new axis but still it is not working.
Destroying the chart and redrawing it is very cumbersome and is not the best approach in my opinion.

```
let charts = Highcharts.charts;

           charts.forEach((chart, index) => {
               if (chart.renderTo.id === `chart-${item.x}`) {
                   this.chosenChart = chart;
                   this.chosenChart.containerHeight = this.chosenChart.chartHeight + 400;
                   this.chosenChart.addAxis({
                       id: item.y,
                       title: {
                           text: item.dimensions[0].name
                       },
                       height: '50%',
                      top: `${top}%`

                   });
               }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce you issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle/codesandbox? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4

Comment: something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-32l9c could not plot the data but if you see the axis is getting added to the same level not bottom of the chart. If you uncomment the parameter called top, the axis is not even showing up as it is getting truncated.

Comment: Do you want to add yAxis or xAxis? Because from your description I understand it as a xAxis at the bottom of the chart. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/whdamoen/ and explain your issue more precisely if you can. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addAxis

Comment: adding axis is not a problem, but wanted to add it below the previous chart. I resolved it using setSize api. Thank you very much for spending time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used setSize of highcharts to increase the size of the container.

something like this below:

this.chosenChart.setSize(undefined,this.chosenChart.chartHeight + 200);

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize

Answer (score 0):

Highchart size rendered with its container width and height.

Even if you changes container hight as your code above, it will not work. Your 2nd yaxis would always similar to this [Example 2 yaxis](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/opposite/)

So i suggest you using 2 charts or highstocks if your data is like that [Highstock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-custom-gui)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80 // like left
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        }
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have to dynamically add many charts, so cannot just hardcode two charts